# Returning API as Object with PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, api, object

I am returning a PHP request as an Array with this:

JS:

```
$('#btnRun1').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "source/php/getCityDetails.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            q: $('#selCity').val()
            },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                $('#txtCityName').html(result['data'][0]['toponymName']);
                $('#txtLat').html(result['data'][0]['lat']);
                $('#txtLong').html(result['data'][0]['lng']);
                $('#txtId').html(result['data'][0]['Id']);
    
                                    
            }
        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // TBC
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);



$url='http://covered/searchJSON?formatted=true&q=' . $_REQUEST['q'] . '&maxRows=1&lang=en&username=covered';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($result,true);    

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
$output['data'] = $decode['covered'];



header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo json_encode($output); 
?>
```

This works as intended, taking the request and posting it to HTML.

I need to do the same for another API request that returns as an object as opposed to an array. I cannot figure out how to re-code these '$('#txtCityName').html(result['data'][0]['toponymName']);' to do so.

Is anyone able to help or point me in the direction I can figure it out? I could not find any solutions on Stackoverflow or Google that I could understand or implement.

Edit: added examples

[image: Return with array]

[image: Return with object]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** is not working with the given code?

Comment: The code works when the API request is an array. I.e. returns like:

Array name (
0: details, details, details
1: 0: details, details, details
2: 0: details, details, details)

But when the return is an object:

Object name (
details)

The code does not work as it is seeking an array.

Comment: Depends on what the object look like but in general I think `result.data.[0].toponymName`

Comment: Edit: added images to original post

$('#txtCityName').html(result['data'][0]['toponymName']); works for the array but I cannot figure out what to change it to for working with objects.

Comment: In JS you use dots to separate object and properties. So something similar to AbraCadaver's suggestion should be right. Which property from your screenshot are you trying to access?

Comment: `$decode['covered']` is an array if you want `result.data.toponymName` do `$output['data'] = $decode['covered'][0];` instead (obviously check its set first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to AbraCadaver!

Changing:

```
$('#txtCityName').html(result['data'][0]['toponymName']);
```

To:

```
$('#txtCityName').html(result.data.toponymName);
```

Is exactly what I'm looking for to return objects.